# hide tier prices on magento product page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I am trying to hide tier pricing on magento product page but am not able to succeed i have followed following post [Display Price Once on Magento Product Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708233/display-price-once-on-magento-product-page) any body can help?

Answer (score 2):

Copy **price.phtml** from

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/catalog/product/

Find the following lines

```
<span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('As low as:') ?></span>
<span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
      <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_minimalPriceDisplayValue,true,false) ?>
</span>
```

comment these lines:

```
<!--span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('As low as:') ?></span>
<span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
      <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_minimalPriceDisplayValue,true,false) ?>
</span-->
```

Your tier price is hidden.

Cheers :)

Comment: Perhaps it would be a better idea to create an own design overriding the default design and there to disable the output.... think of later upgrades

Comment: how about hiding the default/original price?

Answer (score 0):

**Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_prices.phtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                 
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
            <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">**Magento_Catalog**::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::custom_tierprice.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>                                                        
</layout>
```

**Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\custom_tierprice.phtml**

```
<?php @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox $block @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice $tierPriceModel ?>
```